# Graph vertex-coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph .

Let $C(v)$ denote a set of possible colors for the vertex $v \in V$. Such that $|C(v)|\ge deg(v)$ and for at least one vertex $w \in V$ $|C(w)|\gt deg(w)$

> Prove there exists a vertex coloring of $G$ such that for every $(u,v) \in E$ 
>    $\;u$ and $v$ have different colors

My idea: I thought I could prove this using induction but if I do induction over $|V|$ I don't know how to continue (How to apply the induction to a subgraph)

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Seems trivial. It would be more interesting if you required the coloring to give each vertex $v$ a color in $C(v).$ Hmm. Maybe this is vaguely implied when you say "$C(v)$ denote a set of possible colors . . ."?

Comment: @bof yeah, that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G'=G-w$. Each connected component of $G'$ has less edges than $G$ and has at least one former neighbour $v$ of $w$. As $\deg v$ got decreased, we have $|C(v)|>\deg v$ in $G'$. So by induction hypothesis (each  component of) $G'$ can be coloured without monochromatic edges.
By picking a colour for $w$ that is not among the $\deg w<|C|$ dolours of its neighbours, we obtain a colouring for $G$ wihout monochromatic edges.